# Go to stage SharePoint worklfow 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Is there a way to model following in SharePoint 2010 workflow platform which allows you to go back to a stage? [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stages are introduced in SharePoint 2013 workflow it is not supported in SharePoint 2010 template.

Comment: That I know, but isn't there a workaround to get similar functionality working using a 2010 workflow?

Comment: Then we should go with normal if else conditions because in SharePoint 2010 workflow transition is not possible

Answer (score 3):

**Is there a way to model following in SharePoint 2010 workflow platform which allows you to go back to a stage?**

Unfortunately, you can't do an equivalent functionality of `stage` in SharePoint designer 2010 , because it's a sequential workflow.

A **sequential workflow** represents a series of steps. The steps are performed one after another until the last activity is completed. Sequential workflows are always strictly sequential in their execution.

So to can achieve this ,  you will need to develop a **state machine workflow** that require a code.

A **state machine workflow** represents a set of states, transitions, and actions. The steps in a state machine workflow execute asynchronously. This means that they are not necessarily performed one after another.

For more details check 
[Creating SharePoint 2010 State Machine Workflows in Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508985.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well this isnt really a solution for SharePoint 2010 environment but applies executing a 2010 workflow inside SP online or 2013.

I'd suggest to create 3 workflows 
1. State A workflow (2010 workflow) 
2. State B workflow (2010 workflow) 
3. SP 2013 workflow which has 2 different states to manually invoke State A or State B
depending inside 2 states. This is allowed and hence we chose this workflow to be 2013

This might apply to some scenario!